# VB.net MS Access is showing weird result at the first row

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, row

I have two tables which are Branch table and Campus_Site table. The two table looks like this

**Branch Table**

```
__________
|Id |Name |
-----------
|1  |A    |
|2  |B    |
-----------
```

**Campus Site**

```
_____________________
|Id |Name |Branch_ID|
---------------------
|1  |C    |1        |
|2  |D    |1        |
---------------------
```

the Column `Campus_Site_ID` is the foreign key to Branch table

So I queried a query like this:

```
SELECT CAMPUS_SITE.* FROM Campus_Site INNER JOIN Branch ON Campus_Site.BRANCH_ID = Branch.ID WHERE Branch.NAME = @branchName
```

And it looks fine in Microsoft Access.

but:

When I run the code in Visual Studio, the result was

```
-CD
-D
```

the first row has strangely appended all the results. What has done wrong to my code

```
Try
    connection.Open()
  Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT CAMPUS_SITE.* FROM Campus_Site INNER JOIN Branch ON 
  Campus_Site.BRANCH_ID = Branch.ID WHERE Branch.NAME = @branchName", connection)
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branchName", ComboBox1.Text)
    Dim dataReader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

    While dataReader.Read
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(dataReader("NAME"), dataReader("NAME"))
    End While

    dataReader.Close()
    command.Dispose()
    connection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: It looks like you're joining on BranchID though, not Campus_Site_ID. Also, investigate using a `using` statement for the connection and command. Also, considering clearing the TreeView's nodes before you execute code just to be sure on what exactly is populating your treeview.

Comment: This is one of those rare times where a screenshot of the problem may be helpful

Comment: "the Column Campus_Site_ID is the foreign key to Branch table" Did you mean "the Column Campus_Site.Branch_ID is the foreign key to Branch table"

Comment: I couldn't send a screenshot of the result but its definitely weird from visual studio compared to the query I ran in MS Access. It's a little bit difference at the first row where the first row in visual studio appended all the result and the rest of the row normal.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer yes I am joining branch to Campus_Site table because I want to select data from Campus_Site table by referring the Branch Name.